# Extending Multiple Interfaces or Creating new Classes in Typescript (Polymorphism)

Tags: typescript, class, interface, polymorphism

I am starting to model an API client in typescript and looking for some clarification on what the right way is to model the data. The Data Models from the API all share a common set of attributes (an abstract), then have more concrete types of each object. There is also a common metadata set that each object will share ($meta), but some of the values of will be different for each object. For instance:

```
type Shapes = "Parallelogram" | "Triangle"
type QuadShapes = "Square" | "Trapezoid" | "Rectangle" | "Rhombus" | "Parallelogram"
type ParallelogramShapes = "Square" | "Rectangle" | "Rhombus" | "Parallelogram"
type TriangleShapes = "Isosceles" | "Scalene" | "Equilateral"


interface Meta {
    id: number
    number_of_sides: number,
    type: Shapes,
    is_quadrilateral: Boolean,
    is_parallelogram: Boolean,
}

interface IShape {
    $meta: Meta
}

interface IQuadrilateral extends IShape {
    $meta.number_of_sides: number
}

interface IParallelogram extends IQuadrilateral {
    $meta.number_of_parallel_sides: number
    $meta.type: ParallelogramShapes
}

interface ITriangle extends IShape {
    $meta.is_parallelogram: Boolean
    $meta.type: TriangleShapes
}

// ISquare should look like: 
//  {    
//      $meta: {
//          id: 1,
//          type: "Parallelogram",
//          parallelogram_type: "Square"
//          is_parallelogram: true,
//          is_quadrilateral: true,
//          number_of_sides: 4,
//          number_of_parallel_sides: 2
//      },
//      name: "Some Square"
//      color: "Blue"
//  }

interface ISquare extends IParallelogram {
    // How do i define the $meta node?
    $meta: 
    name: string,
    color: string
}

class Square implements ISquare {
    $meta: ?
    name: string,
    color: string

    constructor(meta: any, name: string, color: string) {
        this.$meta: meta
        this.name: name.
        this.color: color
    }
}
```

I am not sure if i am missing something, but the biggest issue i am having is how to model the `$meta` paramter into the interfaces. How can i set the `$meta.type` and `$meta.is_parallelogram` in a consistent, non-redundant manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My inclination would be to refactor so that your `Meta` types form their own interface hierarchy, and have `IShape` be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) in the type of `Meta` it supports.

First I'll rewrite your types.  Note that for consistency I think you want `Shapes` to be `TriangleShapes | QuadShapes` because subtyping requires that if `Square` implements `IShape` that the `type` property to be assignable to `IShape`'s `type` property.  But `"Square"` is not assignable to `"Parallelogram" | "Triangle"`, since these are [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) types and only refer to particular strings:

```
type Shapes = TriangleShapes | QuadShapes
type QuadShapes = "Trapezoid" | ParallelogramShapes
type ParallelogramShapes = "Square" | "Rectangle" | "Rhombus" | "Parallelogram"
type TriangleShapes = "Isosceles" | "Scalene" | "Equilateral"
```

Now we talk about the `Meta` hierachy.  This, I think, involves a minimum of redundancy, as you only have to specify the properties which are new or narrower compared to the properties of their supertypes:

```
interface Meta {
    id: number
    number_of_sides: number,
    type: Shapes,
    is_quadrilateral: boolean, // Boolean is an object type, use boolean instead
    is_parallelogram: boolean, // ditto
}


interface QuadrilateralMeta extends Meta {
    number_of_sides: 4;
    type: QuadShapes;
    is_quadrilateral: true;
}

interface ParallelogramMeta extends QuadrilateralMeta {
    type: ParallelogramShapes;
    is_parallelogram: true;
}

interface TriangleMeta extends Meta {
    type: TriangleShapes;
    is_quadrilateral: false;
    is_parallelogram: false;
}

interface SquareMeta extends ParallelogramMeta {
    type: "Square"
    number_of_parallel_sides: 2; // not sure
}
```

Now we introduce the generic `IShape`:

```
interface IShape<M extends Meta> {
    $meta: M
}
```

And `ISquare` can be concisely described by specifying the generic `M` and adding the new properties:

```
interface ISquare extends IShape<SquareMeta> {
    name: string;
    color: string;
}
```

And finally your class:

```
class Square implements ISquare {
    constructor(public $meta: SquareMeta, public name: string, public color: string) { }
}
```

Hope that works for you or gives you ideas.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=5#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-WLAYkZBu41Pbag0yO3TJtRp6VIuUo-re2CvFwBolB1Dm3NWEMZzn2SuuKmnNq7fbZ8EkBnMY5QABMrKgAHpx0spMAoMgGC53cX5ajy3l9AAeYYamsksljBAAPkpGYAJDoD4thkvZSuy0N122d1rUOubBvHM4IOTj0bHgQrAgRZkHFboiFtWZvD+KRsGA0DiCLWUuG8ZpkFQT8VGgXAdDAMgLx6V8MJcE9HigggQIlXwYIACjABhwhIXBvCgc9LwrL9yXOKA6IYpilkAuC8GILieMY5ioM0WC53gogAEpJigGUPU4IA)

Comment: So this is working great! Thank you for your help. One question and I may be adding a level of abstraction that is unnecessary here, but what is Meta were a generic:, like `Meta<T>` where the `type` were set to the generic Shapes<T>

Comment: I don't know the use case well enough to opine about whether making `Meta` and/or `Shapes` generic is worthwhile.

Comment: Right...i went down that Rabbit-hole and it turned into Generics-hell. So i decided 4 or 5 interfaces was going to be easier. Thank you again!